# Connecting jaeger with elasticsearch backend storage on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, elastic, storage

I have a kubernetes cluster on google cloud platform, and on it, I have a jaeger deployment via development setup of [jaeger-kubernetes templates](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes#development-setup) 
because my purpose is setup `elasticsearch` like backend storage, due to this, I follow the jaeger-kubernetes github documentation with the following actions

- I've created the services via [production setup](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes#production-setup) options

Here are configured the URLs to access to `elasticsearch` server and username and password and ports

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/production-elasticsearch/configmap.yml
```

And here, there are configured the download of docker images of the elasticsearch service and their volume mounts.

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/production-elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

And then, at this moment we have a elasticsearch service running over 9200 and 9300 ports

```
 kubectl get service elasticsearch                                                                                                                                [a89fbe2]
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
elasticsearch   ClusterIP   None         <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   1h
```

- I've follow with the creation of jaeger components using the `kubernetes-jaeger` [production templates](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes#jaeger-components) of this way:

---

```
λ bgarcial [~] → kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/jaeger-production-template.yml        
deployment.extensions/jaeger-collector created
service/jaeger-collector created
service/zipkin created
deployment.extensions/jaeger-query created
service/jaeger-query created
daemonset.extensions/jaeger-agent created

λ bgarcial [~/workspace/jaeger-elastic] at  master ?
```

According to the [Jaeger architecture](https://eng.uber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Distributed_Tracing_Header.png), the `jaeger-collector` and `jaeger-query` services require access to backend storage.

And so, these are my services running on my kubernetes cluster:

```
λ bgarcial [~/workspace/jaeger-elastic] at  master ?
→ kubectl get services                                                                                  [baefdf9]
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                        AGE
elasticsearch      ClusterIP      None            <none>           9200/TCP,9300/TCP              3h
jaeger-collector   ClusterIP      10.55.253.240   <none>           14267/TCP,14268/TCP,9411/TCP   3h
jaeger-query       LoadBalancer   10.55.248.243   35.228.179.167   80:30398/TCP                   3h
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.55.240.1     <none>           443/TCP                        3h
zipkin             ClusterIP      10.55.240.60    <none>           9411/TCP                       3h

λ bgarcial [~/workspace/jaeger-elastic] at  master ?
```

- I going to `configmap.yml` elastic search file  `kubectl edit configmap jaeger-configuration` command in order to try to edit it in relation to the elasticsearch URLs endpoints (may be? ... At this moment I am supossing that this is the next step ...)

I execute it:

```
λ bgarcial [~] → kubectl edit configmap jaeger-configuration
```

And I get the following edit entry:

```
 apiVersion: v1
data:
  agent: |
    collector:
      host-port: "jaeger-collector:14267"
  collector: |
    es:
      server-urls: http://elasticsearch:9200
      username: elastic
      password: changeme
    collector:
      zipkin:
        http-port: 9411
  query: |
    es:
      server-urls: http://elasticsearch:9200
      username: elastic
      password: changeme
  span-storage-type: elasticsearch
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2018-12-27T13:24:11Z"
  labels:
    app: jaeger
    jaeger-infra: configuration
  name: jaeger-configuration
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1387"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/jaeger-configuration
  uid: b28eb5f4-09da-11e9-9f1e-42010aa60002
```

Here ... do I need setup our own URLs to collector and query services, which will be connect wiht elasticsearch backend service?

How to can I setup the elasticsearch IP address or URLs here?

In the jaeger components, the query and collector need access to storage, but I don't know what is the elastic endpoint ...

Is this `server-urls: http://elasticsearch:9200` a correct endpoint?

I am starting in the kubernetes and DevOps world, and I appreciate if someone can help me in the concepts and point me in the right address in order to setup jaeger and elasticsearch as a backend storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resolving a service in Kubernetes,

> Assume a Service named foo in the Kubernetes namespace bar. A Pod running in namespace bar can look up this service by simply doing a DNS query for foo. A Pod running in namespace quux can look up this service by doing a DNS query for foo.bar.

Since Jaeger is in the same namespace, then yes, it can resolve the Elasticsearch endpoint with just `elasticsearch`. Your configuration is correct in that respect and requires no changes.

If Jaeger were located in another namespace, you could specify the full DNS record `elasticsearch.default.svc.cluster.local`.